# Kubernetes Engine - Pod deployment not updating to the latest image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I’m following this tutorial for Google Cloud Platform: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app . Basically I cloned the example `hello-app` project from Github both on Google Cloud (using Google cloud shell) and locally on my machine because I want to practise doing this tutorial, using both the cloud approach and my local machine (using Google Cloud SDK) - where I would then push the Docker image to the cloud, build and run it thereafter on Kubernetes.

1- My first, when I got to step 8, where I changed the source code string from “Hello, World” to “Hello, world! Version 2”, and string “Version: 1.0.0” to “Version: 2.0.0” in the Go file, basically the lines:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, world! Version 2\n")
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Version: 2.0.0\n")
```

I realised that I changed the source code on my local machine (not the one on the cloud). I then went to the Google Cloud Shell in the Console, re-built a Docker image with `v2` tag, then pushed it to the Google Container Registry (not realising that I’m building an image from the unchanged code project stored on the cloud, rather than the one from my local machine). When I applied a rolling update to the existing deployment with an image update using `kubectl`, not surprisingly, it didn’t work. 
So basically to fix this, I need to build an image from the (changed) source code project on my local machine and push that image to the Google Container Registry (using Google Cloud SDK shell). That’s the theory (I’m assuming at least from my understanding). I created an image with exactly the same tag (i.e. v2), bearing in mind there’s already a v2 image (with the unchanged code) stored in the Container Registry, done from my previous step. I wondered if it would simply overwrite the existing image in the Container Registry, which it did (looking the Container Registry > Images section, I can see a v2 image with Update showing just a few seconds ago). 
Now everything is set for the final step, which is apply a rolling update to the existing deployment with an image update:

```
kubectl set image deployment/hello-web hello-web=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-app:v2
```

This was successful as I got the response:

```
deployment.extensions/hello-web image updated
```

However, when I navigated to Kubernetes Engine > Workloads, to view the deployed app on Kubernetes, although the status shows = `OK`, in the `Managed pods` section it shows the pods running from yesterday and the day before (in the `Created on` date column), not the deployment of today (June 29th):

[image: Kubernetes - Managed Pods]

1 (a) - which brings me to side question (still relating to the first question), The `Revision` column in the table above, does this mean the number of times I deployed new pods from an image? Because indeed I did try this step a few times, in a vain attempt to fix the issue (I think it might’ve been 4 times). 
Going back to the main question, similarly if I try the external IP from the Load Balancer service, to load the site, it doesn’t show the changed code. Also, when I check the latest image pushed in the Container Registry, by navigating to Container Registry > Images, I can see a v2 of the image uploaded minutes ago. So the Container Registry does have the latest image I uploaded (meaning it overwritten the previous version 2 of the same image name in the Container Registry. Otherwise it should’ve failed if it couldn’t overwrite it). So I don’t quite understand, shouldn’t the last step (below) meant to deploy that last image v2 from the Container Registry?:

```
kubectl set image deployment/hello-web hello-web=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/hello-app:v2
```

I’m not sure what I’m missing.

2- As I’m new to Docker, I was wondering is there a way to pull the image from the Container Registry, and view the source code in the Image. Otherwise, how is it possible to verify which Image contains which version of the source code? This can cause much confusion, with many versions of images along with equally many versions of source code history changes. How can you tell which source code commit corresponds to which Docker image?

3- Finally, can anyone advise on best practices of managing Kubernetes, in different scenarios. Say in the scenario where you deployed a container from an updated image version, but realised after there are issues or missing features, so you want to roll-back to the previous deployment. So is there best practises for managing such scenarios.

Apologies for the long-winded text, and many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a change to a deployment, Kubernetes only actually does something if you're making some change to the text of the deployment.  In your example, when you `kubectl set image ...:v2`, since the deployment was already at v2, it sees that the current state of the pods matches what it expects and does nothing.  If you `kubectl delete pod` that can cause them to get recreated, but again Kubernetes will see that it already has a v2 image on the node and start it again.

The simplest cleanest way to do this is to just decide you've published a v2, if not the v2 you expected, and build/push/deploy your changed image as v3.

(Also consider an image versioning scheme based on a source control commit ID or a datestamp, which will be easier to generate uniquely and statelessly.)

Comment: Thank you v much David. Worked like a charm :) Great to run into this issue now, and understand how Kubernetes works with image versions. I do have a few questions following up from your explanation. Just to clarify, you mentioned that the Deployment sees the current state of the pods matches what it expects and does nothing. So does the Deployment actually checks what the image name and version is in the Container within the Pod, or does it check elsewhere in the Pod, for the image?

Comment: My second question, you mentioned that even after deleting the pod, Kubernetes (does Kubernetes and Deployment can be used interchangeably in this context or are they different?) will see that it already has a v2 image on the node. So does this mean the image is recorded/located both on the Container of the Pod and the underlying Node resource as well? I'm trying to differentiate between all these elements in the Kubernetes hierarchy: Deployment, Pod, Container, Node. Trying to understand which one of these components Kubernetes looks into when it's checking for the image and updating it.

Comment: Thirdly, Regarding considering an image versioning scheme based on a source control commit ID, is there a guide you can point me to on how to set Docker Image versioning same as source control commit ID/Date in an automated way (perhaps via a CI server config, yml file, or other ways)?

Comment: Finally, is there a way to look into the source code of the application within a Docker Image. Say for example, there’s been a mess up in the versions and you’re no longer sure which Docker Image corresponds with which source code version. As kindly suggested below by Andreas to use `--entrypoint bash`. I’m still not sure how to use that to explore the source code of, say, the `main.go` file in the tutorial within the Docker Image ...

Comment: I tried `docker run -it --entrypoint bash open -a vim main.go gcr.io/sunlit-mix-243915/hello-app:v2`, but got the error: `Unable to find image 'open:latest' locally docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for open, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login`. I used: `gcloud auth configure-docker` to authenticate & managed to pull the v2 image successfully on Google Cloud Shell VM. So not sure how to open source code file.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions. If it's more within the ettiquette of StackOverflow to ask these questions in new posts, I'm happy to do that. Many thanks again for the help.

Comment: You can use `kubectl get pod ... -o yaml` to see the created pod; Kubernetes does the same thing internally when it sees a deployment change, and the image's name/tag is recorded there.  When the pod already has the right image string, nothing happens, even if the image might have changed on the remote server.

Comment: SO style is generally to ask one question per question, so some of these are better as new questions.  A CI system is a good way to assign image tags, or a short shell script.  Since Go is a compiled language you can't see the source code from just a Docker image.

Comment: Oh I see. So Kubernetes checks in the Pod for the image name and tag, when setting an image update to the Deployment. Cool, I'll keep it to one question in future, thanks David. That's a real problem, if there's a mess up in the Image version tagging then there's no way of checking what source code was in that image. I may ask this question in a new post, on what's the best way to tackle this issue, which I'm sure can happen during development. Thanks again.

Comment: What is being stated here is true but how do we set the deployment image section to pull the latest image. Helm can be one solutions. I have created images based on commit_sha and pushed to containerRegistry in GCP but now trying to figure out to set the latest image being build to k8s deployment

Answer (score 1):

1-) Are you sure that :v2 isn't already running?

1a) revision is the revision of the Deployment. Every change you make increases the revision. Changing the image from :v1 to :v2 should change it.

2) you can launch any specific image with `--entrypoint bash` and browse around. If your code is readable you can read it as on any other computer. If it's compiled it gets harder.

On the other hand, you should trust your build process/build pipeline to properly tag the build and just checking the tag should be enough to be confident that the correct version is running.

Comment: 1-) I looked into each Pod detail view, in there under the Container section (container called `hello-web`), and under the image column it shows it's using image `gcr.io/sunlit-mix-243915/hello-app:v2`. Unless the image itself doesn't have the changed code. What's the best way to check this? Shall I pull the image from the Container in Google Cloud?

Comment: 1a) I pushed :v2 a few times because I kept on re-building the same v2 image from my local machine, with the changed code, pushing it to the Google Container Registry and then re-deploying it to the Pods. So I take it, it's not just about counting v1 and v2 (i.e. the change in tags) but how many times you re-deploy an image to a Container within the Pod.

Comment: So, when you push several :v2 kubernetes will not think that anything change. Further, it will not pull the changed :v2 unless instructed to. You can set imagePullPolicy to Always and it will pull the image on every pod start. (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#updating-images). Change to always and kill all current pods and the new ones will have your latest code. Note, it's better to just give it a new and uniq tag.

Comment: 2) Regarding `--entrypoint bash`, I'm not sure what argument to pass to open, say, `main.go` file which has the source code I need to check. I tried `docker run -it --entrypoint bash open -a vim main.go gcr.io/sunlit-mix-243915/hello-app:v2`, but I got the error: `Unable to find image 'open:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for open, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.`.  I used: `gcloud auth configure-docker` to authenticate & managed to pull the `v2` image succesfully on Google Cloud Shell VM. So not sure how to open source code file

Comment: Many thanks Andreas for the answers. I had two answers from yourself & David (first answer). Very kind of you both for the help. I would set both answers with green ticks (accepted answers) if StackOverflow would allow it, but it doesn't. I've ticked David's answer, purely because it was the first and solved the issue by mentioning to simply create a new version of the image, as Kubernetes won't apply the update for existing image version. Although you did also mention that in your comment section. But I can't tick both answers. Anyway I upvoted your answer as well. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to pull policy of Kubernetes. You can force the pull policy to be always or use a unique image name.https://kukulinski.com/10-most-common-reasons-kubernetes-deployments-fail-part-1/.